# How do I get `pdb` to return from calling a file within another file?

Tags: python, python-2.7, debugging, pdb

I have one file that I'm executing (let's call it `main.py`):

```
import anotherfile as afile
afile.main()
```

And inside `afile`, I have :

```
def main():
   import pdb
   pdb.set_trace()
```

So, from the terminal I run `python main`.  But, this does not set the trace.  It doesn't interrupt the execution at all.

How can I use `pdb` when calling it from another file?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I cannot yet comment, posting this as an answer - are you sure you're importing the right 'anotherfile.py'? Print something just before `import pdb` to make sure it gets executed.

Unless your `pdb` module is broken, the above should most definitely start the `(Pdb)` prompt.